# Getting NameNotFoundException when trying to get OpenMQ connection factory using JNDI

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, jms, integration, jndi

I am trying to use OpenMQ 5.0 with Tomcat through JNDI. Below are the configurations I have made in Tomcat.

`server.xml`:

```xml
<Resource name="jms/sampleFactory" 
          auth="Container"   
          type="com.sun.messaging.QueueConnectionFactory" 
          description="OpenMQ Queue Connection Factory"
          factory="com.sun.messaging.naming.QCFObjectFactory" 
          securityPort="7676"
          parm="--"
          subnet="0"
          host="-s localhost"
          ackTimeout="-t 30000"
          version="1.1" />
<Resource name="jms/sampleQueue" 
          auth="Container" 
          type="com.sun.messaging.Queue" 
          description="OpenMQ Queue"
          factory="com.sun.messaging.naming.QObjectFactory" 
          destName="sampleQueue"
          version="1.1" />
```

`context.xml`:

```xml
<Context>    
    <ResourceLink global="jms/sampleFactory" name="jms/sampleFactory" 
        type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
    <ResourceLink global="jms/sampleQueue" name="jms/sampleQueue" 
        type="javax.jms.Queue"/>
</Context>
```

Web application `web.xml`:

```xml
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jms/sampleFactory</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref> 
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jms/sampleQueue</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.Queue</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Now , when I try to do `initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jms/sampleFactory")` it throws `NameNotFoundException`.

Broker is up and running.

Can anyone guide me what can be the issue?

Comment: I don't know OpenMQ, but if you specify a connection factory's name as "jms/SampleFactory" I would expect to have to use the SAME name in the JNDI lookup. Did you try initialContext.lookup("jms/sampleFactory") ?

Comment: Thanks Axel for responding. Actually, I had done configurations but somehow it was not reflecting. I restarted tomcat and it worked fine.